# Dynamic type select in keystonejs model

Tags: node.js, mongoose, keystonejs

I would like to use a combobox at the adminUI with fields that come from a webservice. I was thinking on get the data with a pre 'find' hook and then override the options atribute at the 'audience' property in the Schema.

Schema:

```
Compliance.add({
  title: { type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true }, 
  url: { type: Types.Url, required: true, initial: true },
  position: { type: Types.Number, initial: true },
  audience: { type: Types.Select, options: [], many: true, initial: true},
});
```

Hook:

```
Compliance.schema.pre('find', async function(next) {
  let audiences = await audienceService.getAudiences();
  next();
})
```

But I didn't find the way to bind the data. Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution for dynamic data fetching?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try making a function from the options:

```
function getAudiences() {
    return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}

Compliance.add({
  title: { type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true }, 
  url: { type: Types.Url, required: true, initial: true },
  position: { type: Types.Number, initial: true },
  audience: { type: Types.Select, many: true, initial: true, options: getAudiences() }
});
```

Result as below:

[image]

Comment: When I use a an asynchronous function from an external service to fill the options I get an error because js can't infer that is an array. 
 Also I'll have the problem that with this formula the function will be executed only when the Schema is instantiated, so I only could have dynamic data if restarts the server and the schema is instantiated again.  It's a good approach but I need to find the way to modify the Schema after it is instantiated or reinstantiate a new one modified.

Comment: If the data is such dynamic why not consider Types.Relationship?

Comment: Because if I use Types.Relationship I have to store and maintain a collection with the data that comes from the webservice.

Comment: In this case I still suggest to use Types.Relationship. You can setup a schedule job to update your Audience model by webservices and at the same time maintain the integrity by not deleting those records that are already referened by model Compliance.

Comment: I mark this like the most helpful answer. In this way works, and works like keystonejs is created to do it.
However I'll still be working on find a solution modifiying the keystone Types.

Comment: what if the data is being queries from the model ?