# Keystone js dynamic select field

Tags: keystonejs

I used `Select` field but creating with manual select option.I have categories list and I want to create another list which includes category field.I would like to do it with fetching all categories into my `Select` field to choose which category I want.How can i do this dynamical ?
Thanks in advance!

```
const { Text, Select } = require('@keystonejs/fields');
const {Keystone} = require('@keystonejs/keystone');
const options = [
    { value: 'YES', label: "Yes, I'll be there!" },
    { value: 'NO', label: "Sorry, I can't make it :(" },
    { value: 'MAYBE', label: 'Not sure yet' },
];




module.exports={
    fields:{
        levels:{
            type:Select,
            options,
            isRequired:true

        },
        tm: {
            type: Text,
            isRequired:true,
            isUnique:true,


        },
        ru: {
            type: Text,
            isRequired:true,
            isUnique:true,

        },
        en: {
            type: Text,
            isRequired:true,
            isUnique:true,

        },

    },


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please read this and reask again

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question (and answer) might be useful to you: [Dynamic type select in keystonejs model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348240/dynamic-type-select-in-keystonejs-model). It was to me.

In short, you can use a function in stead of an array for `options`. With the function returning an array for the `options`.